# How to remember checkbox status Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, view

My app has a list of skills to choose from. When you click on 'Save', user id and skill id are recorded in the database.

[image: checkboxes]

If the user visits this page again, all checkboxes are turned off.

How to check from the database so that the selected checkboxes are always included in the view?

My view:

```
= form_for(:skill_list, url: user_skill_list_index_path) do |f|
 %li
  = f.check_box(:a1, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a1, 'Programming')
%li
  = f.check_box(:a2, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a2, 'Communication')
%li
  = f.check_box(:a3, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a3, 'Problem-solving')
%li
  = f.check_box(:a4, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a4, 'Teamwork')
%li
  = f.check_box(:a5, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a5, 'Creative')
%li
  = f.check_box(:a6, class: 'm-enabled')
  = f.label(:a6, 'Marketing')
```

My controller:

```
def create
  @skill_record = UserSkillList.where(user_id: current_user.id).first

  skill_params = params[:skill_list]
  skills = []

  skill_params.each do |k, v|
    if v == '1'
      id = k.dup
      id.slice!(0).to_i
      skills << id
    end
  end

  if @skill_record.blank?
    UserSkillList.create(user_id: current_user.id, skill_id: skills)
  else
    @skill_record.update_attributes(skill_id: skills)
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
```

My db record:

[image: db-record]

Answer (score 0):

[Rails check_box](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

It accepts 2 parameters `checked` and `unchecked` value

=> For example, if a1, a2,.. are `boolean` field then it should be

```
= f.check_box :a1, {class: 'm-enabled'}, true, false
```

=> For example, if a1, a2,.. are any `string` field then it should be

```
= f.check_box :a1, {class: 'm-enabled'}, "value-for-checked", "value-for-unchecked"
```

Comment: But 'a1' is just the name of the checkbox, by which I determine its serial number for writing to the database.

Comment: @РоманОкс I guess you are using form_for which is used for any object and so i believe a1, a2 .. should be attributes of the object `skill_list `.

Comment: @РоманОкс the value stored corresponding to each attribute is compared with the checked and unchecked value and it works the way. Hopefully, you understand it.